# Apache Ignite cluster in AWS using IP without Multicast

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, distributed-computing, gridgain, ignite

I want to have a cluster of 2 instances in AWS, and want to use static IP Finder. But ignite is not able to find the nodes in cluster and hanged on the message below.

*[18:49:54] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]*

My example ignite config for static ip finder is mentioned below.
Here I have tried with public Ip address of my AWS instance as well as private IP address of AWS instance, but it didnt work and couldn't find the cluster nodes.

**My Ignite Config for Static ip finder is below:**

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
         <property name="addresses">
            <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
            <value>11.33.50.14:47500..47509</value>
            <value>11.33.49.180:47500..47509</value>
            </list>
       </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: Are the security groups for the instances configured appropriately to allow the required communication between the two instances?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you didn't allow the connections on ports that Ignite uses. By default there are two ports required:

- 47500 for discovery
- 47100 for all other communication

Note that if there are more than one node per instance, nodes can all use subsequent ports (47501,47502,... and 47101,47102,...).